# Java 8U60 applet not working if it is hidden in IE 11

Tags: java, applet

I have set applet inside div like this:

```
<div id="Applet" style="visibility:hidden;height:0px;width:0px;overflow:hidden;">
```

In java version 8U51 this work like dream and also all previous Java version. But, after update, 8U60 this does not work anymore in IE. Though the example this works like dream in Firefox.

So, IE version is same and 8U51 works and 8U60 not, problem is inside Java. Anybody now how this fix without setting style to visible ?

Answer (score 2):

The bug is known, has been officially reported and is still unresolved at this day: [JDK-8133665 : REGRESSION: Applet not loaded in 8u60 and 8u65](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8133665)

If you know exactly all the applet tag parameters, you can write dynamically the  element in javascript when you decide to display / make visible your hidden div, for instance with jQuery using the append() or html() method:

```
$("#myAppletContainer").html("<applet code='...' object='...'><param name='x' value='y'/>...</applet>");
```

If you prefer to use [deployJava.js](https://www.java.com/js/deployJava.js), you can still pretty much do the same thing. See [Using deployJava.runApplet to target specific element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13517790/using-deployjava-runapplet-to-target-specific-element) responses for inspiration. As for me, I modified slightly the deployJava script to provide the HTML element in which write my applet tag, as explained in the response of Christophe Roussy.

Either way works fine with IE 11 and Java 8u60.

Comment: The bug is known and has been officially reported here: http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8133665

Comment: Indeed, thank you Mathieu! I add the info in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Only solution I found is make it visible but too small to be seen ;).

```
style="position:absolute;top:0;width:0;height:0;"
```

But I still have some slowness …

Comment: I've had the same issues - it seems that if the applet appears to be shown for the browser it loads perfectly fast. Just put it in a <div style='position:absolute;top:-100px; left:-100px'> and it works well (for me).