# SelectOneMenu not working, getting TypeError: $.browser is undefined

Tags: jquery, primefaces

I am trying to use the `selectonemenu` element of primefaces but when I click on the dropdown arrow, nothing happens.

I am using `Primefaces 5.0.1`.

This is the order of the scripts I include:
**Head:**
`<h:outputScript name="js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.2-respond-1.1.0.min.js"/>`
**Before the < / h:body> (*at the layout.xhtml template*):**

```
<h:outputScript name="js/vendor/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"/>
<h:outputScript name="jquery/jquery-plugins.js" library="primefaces"/>
<h:outputScript name="js/vendor/bootstrap.min.js"/>
<h:outputScript name="js/main.js"/>
```

**What I've tried so far**

1. I've tried including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14798403/typeerror-browser-is-undefined) `browser` definition into the `document.ready` function but I am getting this error `TypeError: n.easing[this.easing] is not a function` and the dropdown menu appears at the left edge of the viewport.
2. Removed the `<h:outputScript name="js/vendor/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"/>` so that only PrimefacesjQuery` would be used, this resulted in a perfectly working dropdown menu, *but also made the dropdown menu at the navbar of the header not working*.
3. Tried including `js/vendor/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js` but got the same outcome as before and these errors at the console:

   TypeError: n.easing[this.easing] is not a function
   TypeError: this.preShowValue is undefined

This is how I am using the `< p:selectOneMenu>`:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <p:inplace id="house-type" editor="true">
        <p:selectOneMenu value="#{houseProfileView.houseType}" >
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Appartment" itemValue="Appartment" />
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="House" itemValue="House" />
        </p:selectOneMenu>
    </p:inplace>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the attribute `target="head"` for all your `h:outputScript`. 
Add `ui:insert` with `h:outputScript` to your head page and then fill it in your template as `ui:define`: [<h:outputScript> target problem when using templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5954963/houtputscript-target-problem-when-using-templates)